# Ошибка сборки проекта в XCode после его переноса на другой ПК

Tags: xcode, objective-c

Перенёс проект на другой мак. xCodы одинаковые, но не могу скомпилить и запустить на виртуальных девайсах. Как быть, в чем проблема?

Подробнее(дополнил):

Перенёс проект на новый мак. Ну скопировал папку со всеми файлами проекта на флэшку. Поставил на новый мак скопировал на рабочий стол. Открываю проект, нажимаю кнопку ран(ну тот что Play иконка) он его вроде как компилит, но не запускает на виртуальных устройствах, после смотрю устройства на которых так сказать нужно запустить, так вот там нет ни чего, имеется только iphone devaice(который даже при подключении афони не работает, не запускает). В window-> девайсах имеется вся ленейка устройств. Но вот когда создаю новый проект, на новом маке, то там есть эта вся линейка устроств. Проект исправен, так как на старом маке работал на ура).

Comment: А что пишет xcode?

Comment: @newbee, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: дополнил вопрос)

Comment: Вся линейка устройств или симуляторов? И Xcode случайно не бета-версия? Версия iOS для симуляторов скачана?

Я на работе работаю на iMac, дома на Hackintosh. Ни разу не испытывал проблем с симуляторами и устройствами.

Comment: раньше норм было, сейчас вот что то хоп и пропал. Ну вот где windows ->девайс там вот есть эти устройства, а вот там где справа от кнопки РАН, там где выбирается устройство на котором надо запустить приложение, ПустО(( только iphone device. При попытки запуска выходит xcode cannot run using the selected device. No supported iOS devices are available. Connect an iOS device to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

Comment: Посмотрите в настройках Xcode->Preferences->Downloads->Components. Должны присутствовать симуляторы с отмеченной галочкой, или со стрелкой для загрузки (нужно загрузить). Второй вариант - удалить и установить Xcode повторно.

Answer (score 1):

Проверить Deployment Target. В последнем xCode его можно установить в 8.2, а симулятор доступен только ios 8.1. Из-за этого в схемах доступен только iOS Device.

P.S. Изменить нужно в таргете проекта, а не в самом проекте.